# How to runlink hotmail account from windows 10?

Tags: windows

I 'm working with a windows 10 (Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.194]) and want to unlink my Hotmail account in windows, I know there is lots of video and links on the internet about this but my problem is that there is no remove or delete button on my setting to do it, its just a manage button that if I click on it it opens my Hotmail account.

I just removed all devices on my Hotmail account but it doesn't work.

Please look at my attached photo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try first to open an local account before you remove the Microsoft account

Here are the instructions:

1. To create a local account on your Windows 10 PC:

   - Press the Windows key + R
   - Type netplwiz, and then click OK
   - Click Add
   - Click Sign in without a Microsoft account (not recommended)
   - Click Local account, type a username, and a password (if you'd like one)
   - Click Next, and then click Finish
   - Sign out of the Microsoft account you want to delete, sign in using the local account 
     you created, and then remove the account you want to delete.
2. To remove a Microsoft account from your Windows 10 PC:

   - Click the Start button, and then click Settings
   - Click Accounts, scroll down, and then click the Microsoft account you would like to 
     delete
   - Click Remove, and then click Yes.